# Chrome not rendering properly in Ubuntu

Tags: nvidia, graphics, google-chrome

I keep getting artifacts when using Chrome in Ubuntu (black bars, multiple pages mixing together, as shown in the attached images). I had the same issue on my old laptop. My GPU card was damaged so I assumed that was the issue. Now I have a brand new laptop (Acer Predator, GPU nvidia GTX 1660 ti) with the same problem. The driver I'm using is 440. I wonder if there's something I could do to fix this issue.

[image]
[image]

Comment: I'm also running into this same issue on Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS on Chrome Version 85.0.4183.102 (Official Build) (64-bit) on a Dell Precision 5540 Laptop (Nvidia Quadro T1000 Mobile) after coming out of sleep. I also see black sections in the browser where it gets funky as you try to refresh the page or move things around. In many cases, I see similar rendering issues that @pceconn posted. I tried upgrading from the 440 Nvidia driver that Ubuntu 20.04 provides with the 450 driver, but that didn't help.

Comment: Even I'm facing a similar issue. After the laptop comes out of sleep, it starts having weird rendering issues in Chrome browser. I'm using Nivida driver on 440.33.01. This issue started recently after upgrading chrome to Version 85.0.4183.83 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Comment: I have this same issue. It did not happen when I first bought the laptop and installed Ubuntu earlier this year, but started a couple of months ago. I have a Lenovo P73 running the Nvidia 450 driver (changing drivers didn't help). Reinstalling Chrome did not help. I am currently running Chrome version 86.0.4240.75, but this has continued through many recent versions.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I solved it by doing the following:

In Chrome:
Go to Settings -> Advanced -> System -> Disable the option "Use hardware acceleration when available"

[image]

Source:
https://support.google.com/chrome/thread/8581885?hl=en&msgid=16395751

If the settings page rendering is too broken to do this, you can run from the command line without hardware acceleration:

```shell
google-chrome --disable-gpu
```

Comment: For me it was Settings -> Advanced -> *System* -> Disable the option "Use hardware acceleration when available" but you got me there. +1

Comment: Very useful --- thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Go to chrome://flags/
And set Vulkan to enable.
[image]

Comment: I've finally had to disable hardware acceleration as suggested in the accepted answer because I was experimenting some issues with e.g. YouTube videos not showing.

Answer (score 3):

The only workaround I have found is to completely restart Chrome after sleep. To do this in a way that preserves your windows and tabs is:

```
chrome://restart
```

I actually made this into a bookmark.

Comment: this worked for me where simply quitting chrome in the traditional way did not.

Comment: What the hell!!! Starting today Chrome 113.0.5672.126 on Ubuntu 22.04 stopped rendering correctly for no reason. I couldn't even go into the options or flags, all I got was jibberish. Various reboots or bleachbit didn't help. But your command brought everything back to normal!